# Read part of text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file as shown below and i want to read everything inside data3 only using python:

```
.......
.......
.......
data1 (
        .......  
)
data2( 
        ........; 
) 



data3 ( 
        a:  1.4e10  ;
        b: 0.3  ;
        Name:   Mat1;
) 


data4( 
        linear; 
)
.......
.......
.......
```

That's what I did:

```
    f = open(text.txt).readlines()

for line in f:
    if line.startswith("data3 ( \n"):
        currentLine = f.readline()
        if line.startswith(") \n"):
            break 
    print (currentLine)
```

I tried to run this program but i got this:

```
currentLine = f.readline()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: Can you please show what it is that you tried already and explain what difficulties you are facing and/or errors you are getting in your code with the full Traceback.

Comment: thanks a lot I updated the question if you can help

Answer (score 1):

This code will search for lines between two points:

```py
rr = [] #Array for saving lines    
for f in file_list:
    with open(f, 'rt') as fl:
        lines = fl.read()
        lines = lines[lines.find('data3'):lines.find('data4')] 
        rr.append(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `f` is not a file object but a list because you used `readlines()` on it already. The line `for line in f:` would already iterate over the lines, you should review how to read files, it is much simpler than you expect. Your code also has another problem, you don't remember that you found a `data3`, so the rest of the entry is never printed.

Try this:

```
data3 = []

with open("text.txt") as f:
    found_data3 = False

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("data3"):
            found_data3 = True

        if found_data3:
            if line.startswith(")"):
                break
            else:
                data3.append(line)

print("\n".join(data3))
```